# Magento test automation framework suite

Tags: magento2

can anybody help me with Magento test automation framework integration with net beans and running test scripts through net beans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is official guide with part about NetBeans integration as well https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/media/docs/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkInstallationGuide.pdf

Also for Magento 2 is better to use PHP Storm because of great plugin available http://magicento.com/

Comment: Thank u for ur response